# Django Add Model Field Dynamically

Tags: django, django-models, dynamic

I saw one application is using the same technique like user can add new field to a existing model. Suppose I have order form like the picture I Have attached below. It has some field for order creating. Now if user want then he can create another field for the order form and can set the fieldtype like email or datatime or text and then make it required or not to submit the form. How they do this using django? Which procedure to follow If I am able to pass the data dynamically how can sync the db without migrate command?? I don't know any good way help me if you can kindly.
check the pictures

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is done through an EAV model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: How can I do this in Django? Can you suggest me some good articles?